# Cannot find name 'Draggabilly'. in Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, packery

```
  ngOnInit() {
jQuery(function() {
            var $grid = jQuery('.grid').packery({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                columnWidth: 100,
                rowHeight: 100,
            });

        // make all grid-items draggable
        $grid.find('.grid-item').each(function(i, gridItem) {
            var draggie = new Draggabilly(gridItem);
            // bind drag events to Packery
            $grid.packery('bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie);
        });

    });

}
```

I am trying to apply draggable component using packery plugin but I am getting error  : Cannot find name 'Draggabilly'.

Comment: have you put the import at the begining of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the typings for any class you're using inside your typescript application that hasn't been defined before .

So for your case , you'll need to import something like [Draggabilly typings](https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly/pull/109/commits/f40f08319eb2f8c8305a6207cf9afb731232dbfe)

Then go to your tsconfig.json and put it's path into the files attribute :

```
"files": [
    "./src/yourTyppingsFolder/draggabilly.ts"
]
```

Comment: Ok , I have saved draggabilly.d.ts file in typings folder now what's next ??